# {{ form }} in html file is not being renderd

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
#python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
from django.contrib import admin
from .import views
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
 login,logout,
 password_reset,
 password_reset_done,
 password_reset_confirm,
 password_reset_complete
 )
#from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.home),
    url(r'^login/$',login,{'template_name' : 'accounts/login.html'},name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',logout,{'template_name' : 'accounts/logout.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$',views.view_profile,name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$',views.edit_profile,name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$',views.change_password,name='change_password'),

    url(r'^reset-password/$',password_reset,{'template_name':'accounts/reset_password.html',
    'post_reset_redirect':'accounts:password_reset_done','email_template_name':'accounts/reset_password_email.html'},name='reset_password'),

    url(r'^reset-password/done/$',password_reset_done,{'template_name':'accounts/reset_password_done.html'},name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    password_reset_confirm,{'template_name':'accounts/reset_password_confirm.html','post_reset_redirect':'accounts:password_reset_complete'},name='password_reset_confirm' ),

    url(r'^reset-password-complete/$',password_reset_complete,{'template_name':'accounts/reset_password_complete.html'},name='password_reset_complete'),



]
```

urls.py(tutorial)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from tutorial import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
#from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),

    url(r'^$',views.login_redirect,name='login_redirect'),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from tutorial import views
from accounts.form import Registrationform,EditProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm,PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import HomeForm


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    def get(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.get)
        return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def home(request):
    numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
    name="jay"
    args={'myName':name}
    return render(request,'accounts/home.html',args)

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('please fill all the fields and make sure new password must be match')
    else:
        form = Registrationform()
        args={'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)
@login_required
def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user' : request.user}
    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("please go back and write correct vaues")
        else:
            form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)
    else:
        HttpResponse("hllo")
        return redirect('/accounts/login')
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("password does not match,go back and try again")
        else:
            form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/change_password.html',args)
    else:
        return redirect ('/accounts/login')
```

forms.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from tutorial import views
from accounts.form import Registrationform,EditProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm,PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import HomeForm


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    def get(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.get)
        return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def home(request):
    numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
    name="jay"
    args={'myName':name}
    return render(request,'accounts/home.html',args)

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('please fill all the fields and make sure new password must be match')
    else:
        form = Registrationform()
        args={'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)
@login_required
def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user' : request.user}
    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("please go back and write correct vaues")
        else:
            form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)
    else:
        HttpResponse("hllo")
        return redirect('/accounts/login')
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
                return redirect('/accounts/profile')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("password does not match,go back and try again")
        else:
            form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
            args = {'form' : form}
            return render(request,'accounts/change_password.html',args)
    else:
        return redirect ('/accounts/login')
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


<!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>home</title>
    {% endblock %}
  </head>

  {% block body %}
    <div class="container">

    <form  method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p  }}

      <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
</html>
```

and browser url

[image]

the problem is with me is that the {{ form }} in home.html file is not being rendered.
also {{ form.as_p }} is not working.

form label(input) cannot appear in web(browser).

and no any error shows in terminal.

please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: Show also your `urls.py`. It looks like you have multiple views defined that all use `accounts/home.html` template, and some of them don't pass the form object into the template - without the `urls.py` we have no way of guessing which one is used.

Comment: the place you are using the `home.html` doesnt have any `form` related to the that view, either change the template in the `register view` or put the `form part` in the `home.html` to the `reg_form.html`

Comment: i have added urls.py in question

Answer (score 1):

its working by change class to function.

```
def HomeView(request):
    form = HomeForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', {'form': form})
```

and also changed

```
url(r'^$',views.HomeView)
```

in urls.py